# kivy: fill a custom shape with color

Tags: kivy

Having drawn a shape in canvas with the Line instruction and points, how can I fill it with a color?

```
canvas:
    Color:
        rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
    Line:
        points: 96, 0, 197, 97, 110, 69, 52, 127
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a single 'fill' instruction, you must draw a triangulated shape that fills the area. If it isn't something with its own instruction, like an ellipse or rectangle, you can use a [Mesh](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.html#kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions.Mesh).